# why is my express POST giving blank in req.body? nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, post

I have checked that my `data` is passed correctly, `db` is connected but also, using `ajax` it gives me success call back with the id returned.

But somehow my data isn't passing through, when I even try `req` or `req.body` I see that `body` is blank like this `{}`

I have this as my form in html

```
                <form>
                    <label for="">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name">
                    <label for="">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="example@hackhub.com" name="email">
                    <label for="">Subject</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
                    <label for="">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="" cols="30" rows="5" name="body"></textarea>
                    <input class="contact-btn" type="submit">
                </form>
```

as for my ajax call

```
    $('.contact-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            'name': $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            'email': $('input[name="email"]').val(),
            'subject': $('input[name="subject"]').val(),
            'body': $('textarea[name="body"]').val()
        }

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url: '/contact/test',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {'name': 'testingaodk'}, // I added this to give it a direct test ( I was using data:data
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    })
```

in my express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/contact/test', function (req, res) {
    var newContact = new Contact(req.body);
    console.log(req);
    newContact.save(function (err, doc) {
        res.send(doc);
    });
});
```

in my console.log I do see `data` passed back successfully with random `id` passed back.

Also, in express console I can see something like this

```
locals: {} },
body: {},
route:
    Route {
    path: '/contact/test',
        stack: [ [Object] ],
        methods: { post: true } } }
```

meaning body is empty but why though?

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need body-parser middleware to parse the body for you.  You loaded the body-parser module, but it doesn't appear you are actually using it.  Without the middleware, the body is in the request stream which hasn't yet been read.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do have `app.use(bodyParser.json());` though, doesn't this use it?

Comment: @jfriend00 on my bad, I figure I didn't post it in the post...let me edit

Comment: You're not posting JSON, you're posting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. You need [`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

Comment: Also, you can simply use `var data = $('form').serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code only shows you using `bodyParser.json()`, but a form submit is not JSON, it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so, instead you have to use something like this so that submitted forms will be properly parsed into `req.body`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

You can decide which options you want to use with the middleware.  Doc is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions).